# Renci SshNet "server response does not contain ssh protocol identification"

Tags: c#, ssh, uwp

I am trying to connect to a remote ssh server using the SshNet package.
My code looks like this:

```
List<AuthenticationMethod> authenticationMethods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
authenticationMethods.Add(new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(SSHusername, SSHpassword));
SSHConnection = new SshClient(new ConnectionInfo(ip, Int32.Parse(SSHport), SSHusername, authenticationMethods.ToArray()));
SSHConnection.Connect();
```

When the program tries to make the connection, I get the following exception:

> Exception thrown: 'Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException' in Renci.SshNet.dll
> An exception of type 'Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException' occurred in Renci.SshNet.dll but
> was not handled in user code
> Server response does not contain SSH protocol identification.

I have been searching for a solution for 2 hours now, but haven't been able to fix it.
Looking through the source code of SshNet if found this error is thrown when the client doesn't get an ssh version from the server. I'm not an expert in this field, but looking at wireshark the server sends a packet with this info:

> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1

I'm pretty sure this is the ssh version it's looking for. So I hope one of you guys can tell me what else I can try to fix this.

My Core project has target framework .NET standard 2.0, the UWP project's min version is Windows 10 1903. The SshNet package is on version 2016.1.0

Comment: You may not be completing the connection so you are not getting a valid response (probably an error message).  You are using a real old version of Ubuntu which probably is not secrure and doesn't support TLS 1.2.  See : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: I am using ubuntu 20.4 but i don't know why it says 0.1